# Load external javascript from CDN on different domain synchronously via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, cdn, synchronous

**Situation:**
A jQuery ajax call goes to a .ascx file that first loads a Javascript file that has 3 variables.

*JS File:*
*var vfirst;*
*var vsecond;*
*var vthird;*

Next, appropriate values are populated into these variables by the .ascx file

*ASCX File:*
--code to load JS File--
--code to populate 3 variables in JS File--

**Problem:**
If this setting is executed in an environment where:

- ASCX File and JS File are on hosted without any CDN - IT WORKS FINE
- ASCX File and JS File are using CDN on the same domain - IT WORKS FINE
- ASCX File and JS File are using CDN on different domain/cross domain - IT BREAKS

**Error:**
TypeError: *vfirst* is undefined

**Suspicion:**
I am using jQuery-1.11.0.js in which I found a method
*jQuery.ajaxTransport( "script", function(s) {*
in which I saw "script.async=true;" by default if the request is cross domain.

**Question:**
How can I fix this? This is posing a huge problem on me being able to load my Javascript resources from CDN hosted on a different domain

Comment: How are you loading them?

Comment: The JS File is being loaded via XMLHttpRequest